# Quick search on huge mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization

I need to index a huge mysql database ( 5 billions record ).
I will rarely create, update or delete

only some request like  SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE name LIKE 'foo%'

I have already set my index on field.

With one will be better for best performance on read request

1 single request on a 5billions records table
or 10 request on 500millions records table and join result after.

Comment: That would most likely depend on the query/how much space your indexes take/how much memory you have/what else the machine is doing/what kind of disk system you have or a few dozen other things. The best you can do unless you want a complete guess is test using your own hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never going to get "good" performance using the `LIKE` clause on a MySQL db that size because it <s>cannot</s> may not use the index.

If you're going to need efficient queries like that then you should consider different storage designs. A common method is to have separate, indexed columns for each length of the string.

For example:

1. foobar
2. fooba
3. foob
4. foo
5. fo
6. f

you will significantly increase the data in your warehouse, but your requirements will demonstrate if this is an appropriate trade-off... is space cheaper than performance? Only you know the answer.

**EDIT:** I see the second part of your question, now. 
You ask whether it's preferable to have one query on 5b records or 10 query on 500m rec and `UNION` the result....

I am inclined to say that you're almost certain to have better results with the single query unless you have an effective sharding system to branch off the queries.... you're going to have to test it to verify on your existing infrastructure.

Comment: Would depend on the queries, a `LIKE` (as the sample query) that does not start with a wildcard should use the index just fine. `%endswith` is a seriously bad pattern though.

Comment: Yes, `LIKE startswith%` is sargable as stated, but I think the OP is understating the question. If it's using the index appropriately then there are fer *simple* fixes he can apply.

Comment: If you forget the LIKE keyword

1 single query (5billions record) SELECT * from tbl_person WHERE name = 'foo'
or 10 query (500millions record) SELECT * from tbl_person WHERE name = 'foo'

Comment: @MathieuBrousseau Against one machine, my guess is that one query is pretty much always faster. The thing about making 10 queries is that you can always scale the query out to 10 machines.

Comment: `LIKE 'whatever%'` doesn't cause significant performance trouble if the  text column is correctly indexed.  It's only `LIKE '%whatever'` that demands a full table or index scan.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of things that you can do.  First, if you regularly search by the persons name, consider partitioning your table by the first or first few letters of the persons name.  See [Partitioning Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html).

For example, since Integers are MUCH faster to search by, you could make a field called **name_abbr** that is a **smallint** that represents the persons first 2 or 3 letters of the their name.  You would index and partition off of this field!  So, **aaa** would be 1, **aab** would be 2, and so on.  Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name_abbr=123 AND name LIKE 'foo%';
```

Now, this will hit the correct partition and the LIKE will only have to check on a much smaller record set.

There are a lot of other things that you can do, but remember that with large data sets, it's always best to break down the data into groups and always try to use integers for queries whenever possible.  Also, make sure to use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) keyword to make sure that your queries are using the indexes and partitions that you want them to use.